# mysql retrieve autoinc value for join insert

Tags: php, mysql

We have the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gp` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `amount` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `status` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N/A',
  `token` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gp_logs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `log` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

We JOIN them, for statistics, but we do this rarely, since the data from the 2nd table is not used too often except when we need to verify things.

Considering that we have many queries per second, how can our query be optimized to use 1 INSERT query instead of two and to insert the correct `id` in the 2nd table (`gp_logs`) that was generated by the INSERT into table `gp`?

Right now, we do a combination of MYSQL with PHP:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `gp` (amount,user) VALUES ('1234','1')");
$id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO gp_logs(id,log) VALUES ('$id','some_data')");
```

We want to eliminate the requirement of PHP for getting the last inserted ID and to insert both entries by running a single INSERT query (with a JOIN).

Comment: It'll need to insert the first record so that the auto-incremented id is generated since you're using that id in the second record - you could move it all into a MySQL function/procedure and use MySQL's `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function. That way PHP only has to make one actual database call.

Comment: Thats not possible either you use `trigger` `after insert gp` on or a `procedure` to take parameter and do the insert part in both tables.